# What's the difference between methods of sourcing frontend socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

What's the difference between these two ways of including socket.io?

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first you have a local copy of socket.io, in the other you are downloading from the cdn (Content Delivery Network). Either is fine, depending on your needs. If you are deploying an application, then the first may be necessary since the site where you are deploying may not allow you access to the CDN. However for public facing websites, the CDN is a good way to go.

Comment: Is the local copy of socket.io the copy in the client's browser? So it's whatever version they have? Whereas the other locks to a specific version?

Comment: No. An address like "/socket.io/socket.io.js" is a path relative to the website root, so it will be translated to something like "http://www.mysocketsite.com/socket/socket.io.js". So it's a copy that *you* provide. Both ways will be locked to a specific version. CDNs are optimised for fast delivery, so that may well be faster than hosting the script yourself.

Comment: Oh! Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: If it answered the question, please mark as answer/upvote. Cheers!